# Observer/Notification vs Delegate

Tags: design-patterns, delegates, notifications, observer-pattern

Let's say I have the following app:

[image]

In this app I have a menu with two buttons, one that takes me to the Posts screen and the other that takes me to only the Liked posts screen.

The actual posts a rendered in the exact same way in both views, the difference is that in one of them all the posts will have the like button selected (Liked posts scree) and the other will have some posts with the like button unselected (Posts screen).

If I'm in the posts screen, for example, and I click the like button of one post, the PostView will report to the PostController that its like button was clicked, the PostController will use the Server class to change the like status of that post and then the PostController will update the PostView's like button to be selected or unselected (the opposite of the state it was before).

Now, if I click the like button to change the post like state in the Posts screen, the like button view should be updated in both places, the Posts screen and the Liked posts screen.
I can think of two ways of doing this:

1) The PostController report (via delegate) to the PostsController that its state was changed, the PostsController report (via delegate) to the MenuController, the MenuController tells the LikedPostsController that some post's like state was changed, the LikedPostsController tells its PostController that tells its PostView to update the like button (if it was changed to selected) or remove the post from the LikedPostsController's view (if it was changed to unselected).

2) Make all PostControllers observers of the Server, then the Server can send a notification every time some post's like state is changed.

Which one is better and why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the Server holds both lists: posts, liked posts, then it would make more sense to let the server notify the interested observers. At the basic level liking/unlinking a post should be handled like a posts list refresh. This simplifies the design of the application, as the components who are interested of any of the two lists can subscribe to that list (observe it), and also provides decoupling between components. Although I must say I'm not too fond of calling this component Sever, as a server component should only make server API requests.

The other approach forces you to add and maintain multiple delegation levels, also couples the components as the root controller will need to know how many controllers will it need to ask to update. And if another list comes into play (e.g. bookmarked posts) you will need to update your controllers accordingly, which can be tedious and error prone.

Comment: I'm simplifying some of the details here, that's why I only have the Server class. Still, the Server don't hold 2 lists, it holds on list of posts and each post has a property called isLiked. The server (or some other middle class actually) can have 2 methods, retrieveAllPosts() and retrieveLikedPosts(). About the refresh, what if I go to the Liked posts screen, click the like button (to unlike it), before the Server response comes back I go to the Posts screen, it refreshes its posts based on the cached posts (that unliked post is still considered liked because the Server response didn't...

Comment: ... come back), then the Server response comes back and that post should change its like button state to unselected in the Posts screen. And I don't wanna do another refresh, because maybe the user already scrolled through the posts.

Comment: I also don't like all that delegate chain either, but I also don't like notifications because it tends to get hard to understand the application flow as it grows. Some times you end up sending a notification expecting only one place to get updated but multiple places get updated and you end up having to create a bunch of conditionals. I was expecting a third better solution maybe =)

Comment: Neither I like notifications, many times are used mainly for convenience rather than design. My suggestion was, if not clear, to have a component, lets call it PostsHolder, that will hold the list of posts in memory, once received from server. And this component exposes two properties - posts and likedPosts (likedPosts can be dynamically generated from posts), and use it to mark a post as liked/unliked. And once a post state changed, it would notify its observers about the likedPosts property having changed.

Comment: BTW, do you have a specific platform in mind? 'Cause I might describe the solution in more platform specific terms.

Comment: Right now I'm building a client side web app, but the notification system I was referring to was from iOS. What you described is similar to the iOS notification system, except it would be done by a custom class. The thing I don't like about this approach is that you link both controllers (PostsController and LikedPostsController) to the PostsHolder, so if you later add another controller that changes the liked state of a post and add it as another delegate, it is not clear from where you are writing your new code which other controllers will end up being updated...

Comment: You would have to hunt down all the addDelegate calls

Comment: Well, in iOS we have KeyValueObserving, which suites well to the PostsHolder paradigm; basically who is interested in posts or likedPosts will register as observers to those properties. No code is needed, excepting the addObserver/removeObserver ones, as KVO is provided by the runtime. On web, depending on the js framework you choose, you might have similar functionalities builtin into the framework.

Comment: React.js would work very nice with your design, btw :)

Comment: React.js is based on data-binding, which I don't like for the same reason I explained in my last comment. I also don't like the key value observer pattern for the same reason.

Comment: Data-binding is not bad at all, it allows decoupling your components and replacing them at any time without affecting other components that depend on it (of the interface is respected). Not sure why you don't like it. However it looks like this got to a long and (not yet) productive discussion, so we either continue in the chat or end it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75328/discussion-between-rodrigo-ruiz-and-cristik).